# Append date to URL to prevent Docker caching + retrieve latest commit from Github

Tags: docker, github, npm, npm-install

I have this in a Dockerfile:

```
RUN npm install -g "https://github.com/ORESoftware/r2g?$(date +%s%N)"
```

But this yields the following HTTP 400 error:

```
[docker.r2g]  npm ERR! Error while executing:
[docker.r2g]  npm ERR! /usr/bin/git ls-remote -h -t https://github.com/ORESoftware/r2g%3F1527384219726226800.git
[docker.r2g]  npm ERR! 
[docker.r2g]  npm ERR! fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/ORESoftware/r2g%3F1527384219726226800.git/': The requested URL returned error: 400
[docker.r2g]  npm ERR! 
[docker.r2g]  npm ERR! exited with error code: 128
[docker.r2g]  
[docker.r2g]  npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
[docker.r2g]  npm ERR!     /home/node/.npm/_logs/2018-05-27T01_23_41_453Z-debug.log
[docker.r2g]  The command '/bin/sh -c npm install -g "https://github.com/ORESoftware/r2g?$(date +%s%N)"' returned a non-zero code: 1
[docker.r2g]
```

My purpose is twofold:

1. Trying to not use the Docker cache (by including a new date).
2. Trying to grab the latest from Github as well (by including a new url).

Anyone know how to do this right?

I tried these two also:

```
RUN npm install -g 'https://github.com/ORESoftware/r2g?'"$(date +%s%N)"
```

and

```
RUN npm install -g 'https://github.com/ORESoftware/r2g?"$(date +%s%N)"'
```

and

```
RUN npm install -g https://github.com/ORESoftware/r2g?"$(date +%s%N)"
```

to no avail.

Comment: Quoting and teh ? causing issues?  Try `RUN npm install --loglevel=warn -g 'https://github.com/ORESoftware/r2g?'"$(date +%s%N)"`

Comment: I tried that, doesn't work, kinda weird, always get a http 400 error. I update the question to show the other two ways I tried it.

Answer (score 0):

I think one of these should do it:

```
RUN bash -c 'npm install --loglevel=warn -g "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/oresoftware/tarballs/master/tgz/oresoftware/r2g.tgz?$(date +%s)"'
```

or

```
RUN npm install --loglevel=warn -g "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/oresoftware/tarballs/master/tgz/oresoftware/docker.r2g.tgz?$(date +%s)"
```

I actually think it was Github that didn't like the URL with the query param, not that it was malformed.